# Implement keyboard navigation in <li> lists using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs

I have used $http service to generate autocomplete to fetch all data of relevant input and its working fine if I am using it with mouse. However, there is no keyboard navigation present in it. I just want to enable up and down arrow movement on the list of options and selection on Enter.

```
<div class="compare-col-head head-pos">
       <h1 class="museo_sans900" ng-hide="hideSearch">Add player</h1>
       <form name="addPlayer1" class="search-form padd-none" ng-hide="hideSearch">
            <div class="form-group museo_sans300">
                  <input type="search" ng-model="search1" class="form-control" placeholder="Search" ng-change="search(1,search1)">
                  <a href="javascript:void(0)"><i class="fa fa-search search-pos search-icon"></i></a></div>
                <ul ng-show="ulShow" class="col-td museo_sans300 playerListUL">
                  <li class="searchPlayerList" ng-repeat="plyer in playerList" ng-click="selectPlayer(plyer,1)"> {{plyer.PlayerName}} </li>
                </ul>
              </form>
              <div class="team-kit" ng-show="hideSearch"><img ng-src="{{playerDetails.KitURL}}" alt=""/></div>
              <div class="team-data" ng-show="hideSearch">
                <h1>{{playerDetails.PlayerName}}</h1>
                <h2>{{playerDetails.TeamName}}</h2>
                <h3>{{playerDetails.fullRole}}</h3>
                <h4>Season points: <span>{{playerDetails.Points == undefined? 0: playerDetails.Points}}</span></h4>
                <h4>Player Cost: <span>$100</span></h4>
              </div>
 </div>
```

I have already tried to search a lot but didn't able to find a solution that fits my scenario.

Comment: you should add `tabIndex=0` in your `li`

Comment: just tabIndex will solve the problem or do I need to add anything else?

Comment: it will allow you to navigate back and forward using `tab` and `shift+tab`, if you want using arrow keys you can add event listeners on each of the `li` and go to next/previous

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did a small fiddle for you, to test it you need to click on first element (because it is embedded in this site)

```js
document.onkeydown = function(evt) {
    evt = evt || window.event;
    switch (evt.keyCode) {
        case 38:
            document.activeElement.previousElementSibling.focus();
            break;
        case 40:
            document.activeElement.nextElementSibling.focus();
            break;
    }
};
```

```css
li:focus{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 1</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 2</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 3</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 4</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 5</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 6</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 7</li>
    <li tabIndex="0">item 8</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This didn't work for me `nextElementSibling` & `previousElementSibling` have `null` values in Chrome.